# Looking for a collection of parsers to extract function/class definitions

Tags: python, c, parsing, ide, gtk

I'm preparing to make a little IDE that allows to expand function/macro calls to their definitions right in the place they are called (and do that recursively if needed, so that if funciton A calls B, I expand B, then B calls C - I expand C in the code of B etc.):

[image]

Question 1: do you know of existing IDEs with this feature?

Question2: How would you implement that? My approach is as follows: I'd like to have the IDE being able to understand various programming languages. In order to extract function definitions, I'll seemingly have to use parsers. Is there any collection of parsers for various languages? I've looked into Ctags and Pygments lexers, but their output is insufficient to accomplish this task.

Preferable language for IDE is Python (although Java and C suggestions are ok, too), graphial library - gtk+2. Thanks.

Comment: in `pycharm` you can go to that object(in your case:on which you want to perform `expand`) by using `Ctrl+b` (for win) or `Command+b` (for mac) when your cursor is on that object.

Comment: @namit Thanks. The same functionality is also available in VIM through Ctags by Ctrl-] to go to function definition and Ctrl-T to return. But this forces you to keep the call stack in your head, which I don't like :)

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: do you know of existing IDEs with this feature?

Not perhaps quite what you describe, but Visual Studio's *Code Definition Window* shows the definition of any symbol at the current cursor position.  It differs of course in that it shows the definition in a separate window to the editor window, but to be honest I would find your proposition somewhat jarring and counter-intuitive since the calls are not semantically in-line.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called "goto definition" in most IDEs.  Granted, they don't expand inline, but you have to put the definition somewhere.

As a general rules, many IDEs have split windows so the definition can be seen at the same time with the original call.   It seems to me that you essentially want to automate the setup of splitting the windows, and going the definition point.

Many IDEs contain internally programmable interfaces.  You can probably do with with Eclipse; you could certainly do this with Emacs, if  M-x goto-definition-in-new-window isn't already built in :-}